# How assign #define with unsigned char

Tags: c++, c

I want to know can assign `#define` with `unsigned char` ??if can how??

for example:

```
 #define ACCESS_PSS {0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D}


    int main(){
    unsigned char ResponseData[100];
    for (int i = 0; i <4;i++0){

                    if (ResponseData[i+5]==ACCESS_PSS){ //how to do this???
                                cout<<5<<endl;
                                              }
```

`ResponseData` from programm get value and byte 5 ta 8 is equal with `ACCESS_PSS`

Comment: It is not very clear. `#define` is a MACRO, works as a textual replacement. What is that you want to achieve?

Comment: @SouravGhosh check the byte on `ResponseData` is right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way:

```
const uint8_t ACCESS_PSS [4] = {0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D};

if(memcmp(&ResponseData[i+5], ACCESS_PSS, 4) == 0)
```

Alternative way (compound literal):

```
if(memcmp(&ResponseData[i+5], (uint8_t[4]){0x32,0xFD,0x6E,0x2D}, 4) == 0)
```

Comment: Just for the sake of completeness: `compound literal (on and above 'C99')`. :-)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Unless a specific version of the C standard is mentioned in the question, always assume the current standard.

Comment: Absolutely sir. Just thought of making it explicit.

Comment: @Lundin can tell to compiler that a #define is an unsigned char??